# React index as key - performance profile

Tags: reactjs, memory, google-chrome-devtools, profiling

I have a virtualised list component that renders 3 elements ( and renders up to 2 buffer rows used for animation - one above and one below the visible items ).

I had it so it used the list item's id as a react key, all worked well. Lately I have been looking into optimising the performance due to some work on a PS3 which suffers from  a lot of memory issues.

I thought about using DOM node pools to prevent so much GC happening and when profiling came out with this:

[image]

As you can see the nodes increase in steps, which correspond to the new items coming in ( old ones will be removed but I guess GC hasn't occurred yet )

When using index as a key - essentially causing it to use a DOM pool:

[image]

The nodes stay constant ( as expected ) as it will reuse the DOM elements and just update their data.

I haven't profiled the CPU for these changes yet - but I'm assuming the latter will have a higher CPU use due to having to update each element, rather than just creating a new one?

Is this a fair summary of what is occurring, or have I missed something?