# Negative performance impact of indexes for keys in React

Tags: reactjs

The react documentation recommends not using indexes as keys due to potential issues with tracking state in the subcomponents and such.
However, it also specifies that it can negatively impact performance.

> We don’t recommend using indexes for keys if the order of items may change. This can negatively impact performance and may cause issues with component state. (The related article does not mention any performance side effects)

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

I am curious what, if any, performance impacts of using indexes there would be.
As far as I understand there is a negative performance impact to use unique keys. As every time a key changes, the components are deleted and recreated. On top of the garbage collecting and component recreation, it would also cause any hooks/componentDidMount to rerun.

Indexes as keys would try and reuse the components and would only update their props. This would also cause re-renders, and any hooks to run if the dependencies change, but if there were no prop changes there would be nothing to update. See example below

```
const data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
return data.map((id, i) => {
    return (
        <Container key={i}> // Component Reused, No Change
            <ShowStackOverFlowQuestionById id={id} /> // Component Reused & Props Changed
            <Button data-i={i} onClick={handleClick} /> // Component Reused, No Change
        </Container>
    );
});
```

Aside from the potential errors to state alignment of the components in an array. Is there any performance side effects to using indexes for keys?

Similar Question With Profiling:
[React index as key - performance profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49095752/react-index-as-key-performance-profile)